# How to hide duplicate rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which I have transferred rows from another Form.
In my DataGridView I have three columns: the first one is `name`, the second is `value`, the third is `id`.
I want to hide duplicate rows with the same `name` and `id`.
How can I do this? My code is not working.

[image]

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Form.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString = Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString AndAlso 
        Convert.ToInt32(Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) = Convert.ToInt32(Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).Value) Then
        Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is the DataSource of your DataGridView?

Comment: It was a dog's breakfast. The code was partially formatted and you had *"enter code here"* still in the question instead of entering code there. I answer a lot of questions here and I don't myself or anyone else to have to waste time trying to interpret a hard-to-read question or editing to make it look the way it should have in the first place, as @Jimi has done on this occasion. It takes little effort on your part to make your question as clear as possible to help us help you. Is that too much to ask, if you'd like us to volunteer our time to help you?

Comment: The posted code is only checking “consecutive” rows for duplication. Given the picture, no two “consecutive” rows are duplicated. Therefore, the code is not going to find any duplicates. In order to remove ALL duplicates will most likely require multiple passes through the grid. Example, the first name is “apple” with id “1.” Loop through the entire grid and remove those duplicates, then do the same with the next “orange” … etc…

Comment: It seems to make sense to check for duplicates as you add new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only compared current row with current index-1 row. So, your code is not working. You need a nested loop to eliminate duplicate rows:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Form.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString = Form.DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString AndAlso
                            Convert.ToInt32(Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) = Convert.ToInt32(Form.DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value) Then
                Form.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next

    Next
```

Here is output

[image: this]